# hbase on ec2 - dns record changed after restart

Tags: linux, hadoop, amazon-ec2, dns, hbase

I am running a standalone hadoop/hbase cluster on EC2.

Everything is running fine however when I restart, I get messages such as `2014-03-18 12:41:53,401 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseRPC: Problem connecting to server: ip-10-73-158-244.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.73.158.244:39781` and eventually hbase shuts down.

This seems to be caused due the fact the the dns record no longer exists but why does HBase look for the old record in the first place? My `hbase-site.xml` has

```
<property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: are you using cloudera?

Comment: no, standard hadoop and hbase from apache